# iterm2 use bash as well as zsh

Tags: terminal, iterm2

I'm trying to set up iterm2 to use bash (as well as zsh).

When I open iterm2 it defaults to zsh.

I am happy with zsh but I would like to add a "bash" iterm2 profile to allow me to open a new tab in bash if so desired.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your default system is *zsh*, your **Terminal** should start with it.
To configure iTerm2 with bash you have to open **Preferences** and change the **COMMAND** on **General** tab on your default profile. You have to enter */bin/bash* or whatever shell you want.

Answer (score 6):

As of 2023, the preferences menu has changed. The solution is now:

- Open Preferences
- Go to the Profiles tab
- Go to the General sub-tab
- Under Command, select "Command" in the drop-down and enter "/bin/bash" (without quotes of course) into the text field.

Restart your iTerm and it will be in a bash shell.

Answer (score 2):

This info appears to be stale. As of iTerm2 build 3.4.19 (2023-0515) there isn't a "command" area on the "general" tab. I believe that you can switch shells by creating a new profile, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34393257)

Answer (score 2):

To change the default shell to bash (not exactly what the OP is asking for, but what brought me to this question), using `chsh -s /bin/bash` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Open Preferences by clicking iTerm2 in the menubar

- then click on Settings
- Click Profiles
- Click + to add a profile at bottom
- Name it bash if you would like
- Then click on Advanced
- Click on the + for Automatic Profile Switching
- Add `!&bash`

Now it will automatically switch profiles to bash when ever you run `bash` in terminal